# SSRS - Custom Pie Chart Legend

Tags: reporting-services

I need some assistance with the following, I have a pie chart with 1 series(Area) and 1 value(Spend)
Now my legend atm is just displaying my Area, but I wanted to add or custom my legend to display the Area and a percentage of the spend. e.g. Los Angeles - 34.5%

How and what should I do to achieve this and what am I doing wrong?

But using this in my custom legend:

```
#AXISLABEL (#PERCENT {P1})
```

[image: Chart Properties]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using multiple values and concatenating them together, you will need to use an expression, i.e `=...`, and use `&` to combine the different elements.

In your case this will be something like:

```
="#AXISLABEL" & " - " & "#PERCENT{P1}"
```

**Edit after comment**

The value displayed by `#AXISLABEL` will depend on what you've defined as the label value under the Category Group properties:

[image]

That said, if you're just looking to explicitly display the Area field, why not just change the expression to look at that directly instead of implicitly through the `#AXISLABEL`:

```
=Fields!Area.Value & " - " & "#PERCENT{P1}"
```

This seems like the easiest option based on what you describe.

Comment: Hi Ian I have tried that but for some reason it is not displaying the AxisLabels for me...its just displaying the % values is not displaying my Area names as indicated in my Series Groups so its not displaying like New York - 20.34%, its just displaying - 20.34%

Comment: Also when I tried to just input the ="#AXISLABEL" in my custom legend expression it display on my graph saying Point 1 for the first Area and then Point 2 for the 2nd area etc.

Comment: I've added a bit more detail and a further expression to try.